# How to change a data pattern in a string using Regex replace?

Tags: c#, regex

How can I achieve the following using `Regex/c#` replace?

Input string I have : " test data : `<test param="p" value="v"/>` input string continues"

Output string I need : " test data : `((test param={p} value={v}))` input string continues "

Comment: Are you needing help with the RegEx or the replace? Show us the code you have so far.

Comment: kinda skimpy on the details - what are some things that are close but shouldn't match?

Comment: all I have is the regular expressions to match the patterns. From what I know you can match a regex pattern (that I can do) and replace it with another string, but I need to replace it with another pattern, not sure how to do that or if it is even possible.

Comment: @CodeJockey, I updated the question to show what exactly needs to be matched and replaced. The string can have a lot of data, but the first pattern needs to be matched and replaced with the second pattern. There can be many occurrences of the first pattern in the string.

Comment: the syntax and options in a replacement expression aren't anywhere near as fully featured as for the match expression, but what you want to be done can certainly be done! If you have a successful match expression, it can probably be adapted for use in a find and replace, so please add it to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your real question is HOW to achieve it, and find/replace requirements seem to be fairly rigid, here is one that works for your case:

```
Find:      ([^:]*): <([^=]*)="([^"])"([^=]*)="([^"])"/>
Replace:   $1: (($2={$3}$4={$5}))
```

The Find expression can be broken down like this:

```
([^:]*)    # Capture zero or more characters that ARE NOT a colon
: <        # Match a colon, a literal space, then a less-than sign
([^=]*)    # Capture zero or more characters that ARE NOT an equals sign
="         # Match an equals sign, then a double quote
([^"])     # Capture zero or more characters that ARE NOT a double quote
"          # Match a double quote
([^=]*)    # Capture zero or more characters that ARE NOT an equals sign
="         # Match an equals sign, then a double quote
([^"])     # Capture zero or more characters that ARE NOT a double quote
"/>        # Match a double quote, a forward slash, then a greater-than sign
```

The parentheses `()` in the regex mean to "capture" any characters matched by the contents of the parentheses. Anything not in parentheses will be "matched", but will be discarded during a find and replace. This is useful for extracting bits of data from a pattern like extracting `name`, `attribute1` and `value1` from `<name attribute1="value1"/>` to then put into another pattern of text.

In C#, you use the System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex object to match or to replace using regular expressions. I believe the syntax/signature (for an *instance* of the Regex object) is `regexObject.Replace(input As String, replacement As String) As String`

The replacement expression contains `$1`, `$2`, etc, which refer to the parts of the match enclosed in parantheses `()`. Thus, `$1` (in the replacement expression) will insert the text matched by the first group `([^:]*)` (from the match expression)

This combination will turn this text:

> "test data : <test param="p" value="v"/>" more text. blah blah blah "test data : <test param="p" value="v"/>" and then some more text...

Into this text:

> "test data : ((test param={p} value={v}))" more text. blah blah blah "test data : ((test param={p} value={v}))" and then some more text...

A great resource for learning about Regexes (and where I learned about 90% of what I know) is [Regular-Expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info), and an associated tool called RegexBuddy is great for constructing, testing, and debugging regexes as well.

Comment: it works correctly. Can you explain how that ([^:]*): in the Find and $1: part in the replace work?

Comment: I tried to explain about the `$1` in the third paragraph (which starts `The replacement expression contains...`), and I'm not sure if that's not clear or if it's missing something. Without going pretty deep into regex internals, I'm not sure what else I can add :D or were you asking more about the match part `([^:]*):`?

Comment: what is that colon doing next to the $1, is it same as equal to in regex? and yes, what does ([^:]*): signify. Sorry, my regex skills are pretty weak. If you are matching each piece separately, why do you need ([^:]*): in the beginning. That : is confusing me.

Comment: ah - I broke down the Match expression, so tell me if that's not clear enough, but in a replacement expression (at least in .Net), the only special character is the dollar sign `$` - every other character is literal. I'll add a little more to the answer

Comment: ok, i see what you were doing. it should not look for test data : in the string. only highlighted portion should be matched. Thats why it was confusing me. let me read on regex a bit and i'll come back and accept the answer.